# to call onChange event after pressing Enter key

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am new to Bootstrap and stuck with this problem. I have an input field and as soon as I enter just one digit, the function from `onChange` is called, but I want it to be called when I push 'Enter when the whole number has been entered. The same problem for the validation function - it calls too soon.

```
var inputProcent = React.CreateElement(bootstrap.Input, {type: "text",
  //bsStyle: this.validationInputFactor(),
  placeholder: this.initialFactor,
  className: "input-block-level",
  onChange: this.handleInput,
  block: true,
  addonBefore: '%',
  ref:'input',
  hasFeedback: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works better than all others solutions given:

```
<!-- html -->
<input type="text" onkeydown='handleKeyPress(this)'>
```

...

```
// js
function handleKeyPress(e)
{
    if (event.key === 'Enter') 
    {
        // call your method here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 689):

According to [React Doc](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#keyboard-events), you could listen to keyboard events, like `onKeyPress` or `onKeyUp`, not `onChange`.

```
var Input = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return <input type="text" onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown} />;
  },
  _handleKeyDown: function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('do validate');
    }
  }
});
```

### Update: Use React.Component

Here is the code using React.Component which does the same thing

```
class Input extends React.Component {
  _handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('do validate');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="text" onKeyDown={this._handleKeyDown} />
  }
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuct/d5exc1pw/).

### Update 2: Use a functional component

```
const Input = () => {
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('do validate')
    }
  }

  return <input type="text" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} />
}
```

Comment: And you would also like to bind the validation process to `onBlur` event.

Comment: +1 The great thing about this method is that the backspace key doesn't fire an event. Great for auto-complete.

Comment: Same solution in a more compact way with reference to the input text: `<input ref='reference' onKeyPress={(e) => {(e.key === 'Enter' ? doSomething(this.refs.reference.value) : null)}} />`

Comment: @musemind Actually, you don't need to use `ref`. `<input onKeyPress={e => doSomething(e.target.value)}` is sufficient.

Comment: @musemind The point to use a class method instead of an inline function is to avoid creating a new function every time when `onKeyPress` is triggered. It is a subtle perf improvement.

Comment: attached fiddle is not working anymore, please check, anyways nice answer

Comment: @wuct you said that according to the react docs one shouldn't listen to the onChange event. Where is this stated in the docs? couldn't find it... All of their examples with controlled components use the onChange event.

Comment: @PardeepJain Thanks for noticing. I've updated the link.

Comment: @c-chavez You are right. I should use "could" in that sentence. Updated!

Comment: @wuct - the function does not "get created" each time onKeyPressed is called

Comment: @memical You are right. It should be created each time the component updated. I hope I can edit that comment.

Comment: I prefer `onKeyUp` since it only fires when the key is released. `onKeyDown`, on the other hand, will fire multiple times if for some reason the user presses and holds the key.

Answer (score 101):

You can use onKeyPress directly on input field. onChange function changes state value on every input field change and after Enter is pressed it will call a function search().

```
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search..."
    onChange={event => {this.setState({query: event.target.value})}}
    onKeyPress={event => {
                if (event.key === 'Enter') {
                  this.search()
                }
              }}
/>
```

Comment: this answer works for me rather than the accepted answer above.

Comment: If you have heavy form I would recommend to create function outside render method and pass it as reference, like `onKeyPress={this.yourFunc}` otherwise fat arrow function will be re created on each render.

Comment: this is working for the case where onKeyPress event is written for input and parent case as well. thanks.

Comment: Or `onKeyPress={event => event.key === 'Enter' && this.search()}`

Comment: `onKeyPress` has been deprecated. Use `onKepyUp`

Answer (score 54):

Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a form control (input) normally triggers a `submit` (`onSubmit`) event on the form. Considering that you can handle it this way (having a submit button is optional if you have only one input):

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    setText(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSubmitted(text);
    setText("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input type="submit" value="add" />
      </form>
      submitted: {submitted}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Implicit form submission (`submit` event on <kbd>Enter</kbd>) is performed when:

- there's a submit button
- there're no submit buttons, but there's only one input

More on it [here](https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/#no-submit-buttons).

Alternatively you could bind your handler to the `blur` (`onBlur`) event on the `input` which happens when the focus is removed (e.g. tabbing to the next element that can get focus).

Comment: This is far more clean than using `onKeyPress`.

Comment: Thought since the target is different, `event.target.value` isn't available

Comment: @Izkata what you say is absolutely correct; my answer might require a different way of handling things in the controller `handleInput` method.

Doing as per my answer would cover you both when the user presses enter while focused on the input and when activating a `submit` button/input.

Comment: In **most** situations in web apps there are no forms, just inputs, so this answer is not relevant to the majority of use-cases, IMHO

Comment: @vsync it might not be relevant to the majority, but still valid for a portion - and definitely not incorrect, I don't think it's worth a downvote?

Comment: @vsync you should have a form element for accessibility. Just as you should not make everything a div.

Comment: Note that submitting on a form will refresh the entire page, as a default behavior of form itself. Don't forget to include `event.preventDefault()` on the onSubmit event to prevent the default behavior of reloading the page.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `event.key`

```js
function Input({onKeyPress}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Input</h2>
      <input type="text" onKeyPress={onKeyPress}/>
    </div>
  )
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  state = {value:""}

  handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.setState({value:e.target.value})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <Input onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
        <br/>
        <output>{this.state.value}</output>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Form />,
  document.getElementById("react")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 12):

I prefer `onKeyUp` since it only fires when the key is released. `onKeyDown`, on the other hand, will fire multiple times if for some reason the user presses and holds the key. For example, when listening for "pressing" the `Enter` key to make a network request, you don't want that to fire multiple times since it can be expensive.

```
// handler could be passed as a prop
<input type="text" onKeyUp={handleKeyPress} />

handleKeyPress(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    // do whatever
  }
}
```

Also, stay away from `keyCode` since it will be deprecated some time.

Answer (score 9):

**React users, here's an answer for completeness.**

> React version 16.4.2

You either want to update for every keystroke, or get the value only at submit. Adding the key events to the component works, but there are alternatives as recommended in the official docs.

**Controlled vs Uncontrolled components**

**Controlled**

From the [Docs - Forms and Controlled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html):

> In HTML, form elements such as input, textarea, and select typically
>   maintain their own state and update it based on user input. In React,
>   mutable state is typically kept in the state property of components,
>   and only updated with setState().
>
> We can combine the two by making the React state be the “single source
>   of truth”. Then the React component that renders a form also controls
>   what happens in that form on subsequent user input. An input form
>   element whose value is controlled by React in this way is called a
>   “controlled component”.

If you use a controlled component you will have to keep the state updated for every change to the value. For this to happen, you bind an event handler to the component. In the docs' examples, usually the onChange event.

Example:

1) Bind event handler in constructor (value kept in state)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

2) Create handler function

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
}
```

3) Create form submit function (value is taken from the state)

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

4) Render

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you use **controlled** components, your `handleChange` function will always be fired, in order to update and keep the proper state. The state will always have the updated value, and when the form is submitted, the value will be taken from the state. This might be a con if your form is very long, because you will have to create a function for every component, or write a simple one that handles every component's change of value.

**Uncontrolled**

From the [Docs - Uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

> In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement
>   forms. In a controlled component, form data is handled by a React
>   component. The alternative is uncontrolled components, where form data
>   is handled by the DOM itself.
>
> To write an uncontrolled component, instead of writing an event
>   handler for every state update, you can use a ref to get form values
>   from the DOM.

The main difference here is that you don't use the `onChange` function, but rather the `onSubmit` of the form to get the values, and validate if neccessary.

Example:

1) Bind event handler and create ref to input in constructor (no value kept in state)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.input = React.createRef();
}
```

2) Create form submit function (value is taken from the DOM component)

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.input.current.value);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

3) Render

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" ref={this.input} />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If you use **uncontrolled** components, there is no need to bind a `handleChange` function. When the form is submitted, the value will be taken from the DOM and the neccessary validations can happen at this point. No need to create any handler functions for any of the input components as well.

**Your issue**

Now, for your issue:

> ... I want it to be called when I push 'Enter when the whole number has been entered

If you want to achieve this, use an uncontrolled component. Don't create the onChange handlers if it is not necessary. The `enter` key will submit the form and the `handleSubmit` function will be fired.

Changes you need to do:

Remove the onChange call in your element

```
var inputProcent = React.CreateElement(bootstrap.Input, {type: "text",
    //    bsStyle: this.validationInputFactor(),
    placeholder: this.initialFactor,
    className: "input-block-level",
    // onChange: this.handleInput,
    block: true,
    addonBefore: '%',
    ref:'input',
    hasFeedback: true
});
```

Handle the form submit and validate your input. You need to get the value from your element in the form submit function and then validate. Make sure you create the reference to your element in the constructor.

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
      // Get value of input field
      let value = this.input.current.value;
      event.preventDefault();
      // Validate 'value' and submit using your own api or something
  }
```

Example use of an uncontrolled component:

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // bind submit function
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    // create reference to input field
    this.input = React.createRef();
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    // Get value of input field
    let value = this.input.current.value;
    console.log('value in input field: ' + value );
    event.preventDefault();
    // Validate 'value' and submit using your own api or something
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" ref={this.input} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Perfect Answer!

Answer (score 7):

You can also write a little wrapper function like this

```
const onEnter = (event, callback) => event.key === 'Enter' && callback()
```

Then consume it on your inputs

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Title of todo" 
    onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
    onKeyPress={e => onEnter(e, addItem)}/>
```

Answer (score 7):

Example of preventing Enter from submitting a form on an input, in my case it was a google maps location autocomplete input

```
<input
  ref={addressInputRef}
  type="text"
  name="event[location]"
  className="w-full"
  defaultValue={location}
  onChange={(value) => setLocation(value)}
  onKeyDown={(e) => {
    if (e.code === "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault()
    }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It should be e.key instead of e.code

Comment: @MiteshK both work for "Enter" https://jsbin.com/tiyuhaqiko/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a common use case using class-based components: The parent component provides a callback function, the child component renders the input box, and when the user presses Enter, we pass the user's input to the parent.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  processInput(value) {
    alert('Parent got the input: '+value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent handleInput={(value) => this.processInput(value)} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this);
  }

  handleKeyDown(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.props.handleInput(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
      </div>
    )
  }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodoItem(value.trim());
    setValue("");
};

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input value={value} onChange={handleOnChange}></input>
    </form>
);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
//You can use onkeyup directly on input field

    const inputField = document.querySelector("input");
        inputField.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
         
            if (e.key == "Enter") {
                 console.log("hello");
            }
        });
```