# Create a key handler for input element with React and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

This should be extremely easy but apprently not.
In a standard HTML `input` element, I would like to perform and action if `Enter` is hit.
I am trying to learn TS and cannot figure out which type fits everything I need.

```html
<input type="text" onChange={handleInput} />
```

```js
const handleInput = (event: any) => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  };
};
```

- If `event: InputEvent` then I can't even call the function, because the event type is wholly incompatible.
- If `event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputEvent>` then I can reach `event.target.value`, but an error says there is no `key` property, which is correct. In this case, the keystroke value is kept under `event.nativeEvent.data`. However, if I go for `if (event.nativeEvent.data...)` then an error says there is no `data` property, even though there clearly is:

```js
// from the console
nativeEvent: InputEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "d"...)
```

- If `event: KeyboardEvent` then I get `event.key` but now `event.target.value` doesn't exist.

I would love to know two things:

1. What is the correct type for this event?
2. Where can I learn about the endless amount of types for these minor differences?

Comment: `event.nativeEvenet` won't work, spelling matters in programming, that's why accessing the `.data` property of it throws a TS error - it's spelled `nativeEvent`

Comment: To clarify, I use an IDE, so any typos are very obviously me typing here.

Comment: The second answer of the following thread addresses your situation: [to call onChange event after pressing Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46896944/1218980)

Answer (score 1):

To listen for a key being pressed down you need `onKeyDown`, not `onChange`.

```
const handleEnter = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") { ... }
}

<input onKeyDown={handleEnter} ... />
```

Comment: Upon trying this the error for `event.target.value` says `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`.

Comment: @RonnyEfronny you'll have to keep both events, the `onChange` to update some local state, and the `onKeyDown` which will use that state, not the (invalid) `event.target.value`.

Comment: After some fiddling I found that if I change `target` to `currentTarget` in this solution, I have access to the `value`. If you add it to the answer I can mark it.