# Pressing Tab to active Enter key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question in react/JavaScript that when I press Tab on the keyboard, I need the Enter key to be triggered or active, so any idea how can I do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272207/to-call-onchange-event-after-pressing-enter-key

Comment: @Sam RQ is my answer working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not sure what you're motivation for this behavior is, your logic is even possible with Vanilla JS:

- [Simplest way to detect keypresses in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089421/simplest-way-to-detect-keypresses-in-javascript)
- [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Minimal example for your use case:

- Click into the input field
- Now press `tab`
- You will see an alert that tab was pressed
- Immediately after, you will see that `enter` was pressed as well (programmatically)

```js
let element = document.querySelector('input');
element.onkeydown = e => {
  alert('key pressed: ' + e.key);
  if (e.key === 'Tab') {
    element.dispatchEvent(
      new KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
        'key': 'enter'
      }));
  }
}
```

```html
<input/>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30837408)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added a working minimal example.